# MVC 4 routing - ignore requests for images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I'm trying to prevent users from making requests to access images on their own in my web application, so the user shouldn't be allowed to make this type of request:

sitename/Images/test.jpg

I've tried specifying a route to ignore in RouteConfig.cs but it still serves images on their own, is there a way to prevent this?

This is what I've tried:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.jpg");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{file}.jpg");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.jpg");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{resource}.jpg");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ignore folder you can write like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{*pathInfo}");
```

if you want to ignore only certain files in folder you can use [this overload of `IgnoreRoute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470170(v=vs.118).aspx) like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{Images}", new { assets = @".*\.(jpeg|gif|jpg)(/.)?" });
```

As you can see `constraints` parameter can be implemented like `RegExp`.

Comment: I've tried that, but it still serves the requests for images. I've tried both examples provided in your answer

Comment: Images folder is forbidden by default

Comment: @DenisWessels sorry, i don't get your case. You don't want to allow uses to get images from direct link, but the should still be able to download them some other way?

Comment: If the user tries accessing the image on it's own like this - http://www/site.com/images/test.jpg - this should not be allowed

Comment: @DenisWessels i just want to know what do you mean by "On it's own"? When you put link to img on your html page browser do the same thing that users do on it's own. Or you have separate Controller that serves your images in respect to user Identity?

Comment: Ok so if that's how images work then it's fine, what about ignoring a request for a file ending in .txt? I'm just trying to understand how routes.IgnoreRoute works but no matter what extension or constraint i pass through to be ignored the file still gets displayed in the browser

Comment: Route.ignoreroute ignore using default routing for controllers. I mean when request cames to server it goes to route and if it finds match then controller initializes, when you don't need to use controller and want just pass static content to user, but sognature of request looks like path to controller you use ignoreroure. So i mean it's not about access to folders, but it's about use or not controller.

Comment: The 'IgnoreRoute' overload is what I was looking for however the above example won't work as the 'name' within the 'url' paramater must match the property name specified in the constraints. That means that instead of "{Images}" the 'url' value should be "{*assets}" to actually work.