# MVC web application with HTML page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC web application with a infocontroller. I would like to add some html documentation files in iis using the folder structure webapp/info. When I do that I am getting ManagedPipelineHandler error.

> Is there something I need to add with the project? Do I change the controller?

```
    HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

    Internal Server Error



    Most likely causes:
    •IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
    •IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
    •IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
    •The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
    •The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.



    Things you can try:
    •Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
    •Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
    •Verify the permissions for the DLL.
    •Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
    •Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here. 


Detailed Error Information:



Module
   ManagedPipelineHandler 

Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler 

Handler
   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0-FHIR 

Error Code
   0x800703e9 



Requested URL
   https://test.bjc.com:443/info/index.html 

Physical Path
   D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\info\index.html 

Logon Method
   Anonymous 

Logon User
   Anonymous
```

Comment: Can you include the error text?

Comment: @Steve0 error included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to ignore the route to the folder, e.g.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{  
    routes.IgnoreRoute("info/");
}
```

for example:

[ASP.NET MVC Routing to start at html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794753/asp-net-mvc-routing-to-start-at-html-page)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/ignore-route-in-mvc/

Comment: can I do that if I have a infoController.cs

Comment: I thing it is better to rename the info folder with the html documents

Comment: you can ignore certain files in a folder, see here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242735/mvc-4-routing-ignore-requests-for-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242735/mvc-4-routing-ignore-requests-for-images)